# Selective page endless scrolling

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have implemented endless scrolling on a number pages using the following javascript which works well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.pagination').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
      if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
        $('.pagination').text("Please Wait...");
        return $.getScript(url);
      }
    });
    return $(window).scroll();
  }
});
```

This is placed in my application.js file.

I have just now realised that I have some pagination links on other pages that I do not wish to have endless scrolling however they are replaced with "Please Wait..."

Is it possible to only have the code above active on certain pages or controllers?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: gem 'jquery-turbolinks'. I am aware of issues with turbolinks however this is not my issue. I need to control which pages the code above applies to.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that this article may be useful for you: https://medium.com/@coorasse/turbolinks-how-to-organize-your-javascript-code-df83d59c0886

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your `will_paginate` a unique `#id` so that they're not all using `.pagination`, which is the reason the other endless scrolls are appending the "please wait".

example:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :params => {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'index'}, id: "posts_pagination"%>
```

Here you also see how to delegate the will_paginate to a certain controller and action.

> will_paginate doesn't always play ball with adding an `#id` so you might
>   want to try and add a `.class` instead:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :params => {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'index'}, class: "posts_pagination"%>
```

And then in your `application.js` – Bind the infinity-script to `#posts-pagination` (if `#id`) or `.posts_pagination` (if `.class`) instead of just `.pagination`:

favorite
I have implemented endless scrolling on a number pages using the following javascript which works well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.posts-pagination').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var url = $('.posts-pagination .next_page').attr('href');
      if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
        $('.posts-pagination').text("Please Wait...");
        return $.getScript(url);
      }
    });
    return $(window).scroll();
  }
});
```

You may want to give the `url` a unique variable depending on your circumstances so that each infinity scroll doesn't fetch another infinity scroll's `url`

just change `var url = $('.posts-pagination .next_page').attr('href');`

to:

`var url1 = $('.posts-pagination .next_page').attr('href');`

`var url2 = $('.comments-pagination .next_page').attr('href');`

And so on.

And voilá. You're good to go.

Comment: Awesome ty. At the top you originally used posts_pagination and later used posts-pagination. Which I assume is just a typo. Is there a convention for id/class names as being either _ or - ?

Comment: Ah, that was just a typo, sry. Yes there's a convention using underscore for id's and "-" for classnames. But it's really down to personal preferences in the end, but it's nice to know if you're working with _ or - when working with a lot of JS and CSS. Cause if you mix it, sometimes you get lost in knowing wether "that class was a _ or - " So it's good to keep it consistent.